# Why am I able to give 6 elements when I am dynamically allocating space for only 5 elements using calloc() function?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int *ptr;
    ptr=(int*)calloc(5,sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("Enter the %d value:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Elements in allocated memory\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("The %d element is: %d\n",i+1,ptr[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
OUTPUT:
Enter the 1 value:1

Enter the 2 value:2

Enter the 3 value:3

Enter the 4 value:4

Enter the 5 value:5

Enter the 6 value:6


 Elements in allocated memory

The 1 element is: 1

The 2 element is: 2

The 3 element is: 3

The 4 element is: 4

The 5 element is: 5

The 6 element is: 6
```

It should allocate space for only 5 elements right?
I am unable to understand why is it allocating 6 integers..
Plzz helpp me..

Comment: C never have had any kind of bounds checking, and never will. It's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure that your code doesn't go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "why is it allocating 6 integers" It doesn't. Why do you believe it does?

Comment: You are not able to. You are experiencing one of the many misleading, confusing and dangerously fake-safe aspects of undefined behaviour,

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But if I give i<7 in the for loop of the same code as mentioned above, then it doesn't print any values stored.. So C does check some bound checking ryt?

Comment: Aside: you should check the return value of ```calloc```, and ```free``` the dynamically allocated storage.

Comment: That's the point of undefined behavior: It's *undefined*. It can seemingly work, it could cause crashes, or it might set fire to your cat. Perhaps not the last thing, but it's unpredictable.

Comment: Modern compilers can check array bounds (gcc -fanalyzer=array-bounds) but this is heap allocated array and I could not convince gcc to complain.  valgrind will be unhappy of course.  While it's UB to read or write 1 past an array, it's fine to generate the address one past an array.  Maybe it's an implementation detail to support that feature that calloc allocates an extra word?

Answer (score 1):

You go to a store. You pick up six candy bars. You tell the cashier you have five candy bars, pay for five, and leave.

Does this story imply people are allowed to take six candy bars and only pay for five? No it doesn't.

There is no guarantee every shoplifter will be caught. This absence of a guarantee does not constitute an endorsement to shoplift, nor it is a promise that no shoplifter will ever be caught.

When you break the C language rules, the language does not always guarantee you will get caught. This absence of a guarantee is not an endorsement to break the rules, nor it is a promise that you will never get caught.

Your sixth array element is the shoplifted candy bar. You didn't get caught *this time*. Doesn't mean you won't get caught next time, or some other time when you expect it the least.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5ra1abdnT).

There is a technical term (or perhaps C-jargon) for this absence of guarantee, it is called [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Any C programmer must be familiar with it.

Comment: This is fun but it lacks matter-of fact infos like the concept of undefined behaviour, which OP seems to have missed and should read up on.

Answer (score -1):

The range of for loop was from 0-5 means you are accessing 6(0,1,2,3,4,5) addresses but you have dynamically allocated just 5. So, changing the range of loop from 0-5 to 0-4 will do the trick. Also, you must free the dynamically allocated memory at the end of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int *ptr;
    ptr=(int*)calloc(4,sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Enter the %d value:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Elements in allocated memory\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("The %d element is: %d\n",i+1,ptr[i]);

    }
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the 1 value:1
Enter the 2 value:2
Enter the 3 value:3
Enter the 4 value:4
Enter the 5 value:5

Elements in allocated memory

The 1 element is: 1
The 2 element is: 2
The 3 element is: 3
The 4 element is: 4
The 5 element is: 5

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.662 s
```

Comment: Answer doesn’t seem to supply a response to the question. The answer evades the question.